Not responsive image on phone emulator
I want to make a super optimized website for the pet project. There was a need to adapt the images so that there would be a high-resolution image on PC screens and a small one on phones.
I made a responsive image that changes size depending on the pixels of the user's window, everything works fine on the PC, but when I turn on the phone simulation in developer mode, everything does not work very well: the image does not adapt, as a result, instead of 300 KB, 1.2 MB is loaded into the DOM, these are huge numbers in seconds, especially if the 3G network.
I have had this problem since the beginning of studying the WEB, I tried to solve it on 2 browsers Firefox and Chrome - it does not disappear. What are the tips for solving the problem?
<img 
 srcset="
 assets/images/image-1280.jpg 1280w, 
 assets/images/image-3840.jpg 3840w"
 src="assets/images/image-3840.jpg" 
 width="100%"
 alt="Cyber Prototype" >

Responsive error

If image bigger than 1280px

If image smaller than 1280px


P.S. I know that i can use the <picture> element, but is there any more elegant solution?
I tried to apply srset
I expected my image to be adapted for phones
As a result, my image does not adapt to phones and loads the user system with an unnecessary large picture

Try to specify the sizes attribute, e.g.
<img 
  srcset="assets/images/image-1280.jpg 1280w, assets/images/image-3840.jpg 3840w"
  sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px, 800px"
  src="assets/images/image-3840.jpg" 
  width="100%"
  alt="Cyber Prototype">

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Dear Siu Pang Tommy Choi, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the actions you suggested did not work, but this immediately brought me closer to a full solution to the problem.
